# Can i create package in the previous folder of, where my java file is currently saved?

Tags: java, package

I use notepad to make java programs. I want to know that if for example my java code resides in the : "D:/programs/hello" folder and i want to declare a package as named "helloclass" in the folder "programs" which is the previous folder of folder "hello" . So what would be the code ... i tried these ways but no luck.

```
package /helloclass;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hellllo");
    }
}
```

or

```
package ../helloclass;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;

class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hellllo");
    }
}
```

how can i do it ?

Comment: No.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_packages.htm

Comment: You want the package name to depend on the directory, but in Java it is the other way around: the directory depends on the package. The package itself is static, since it belongs to the fully qualified name and the class may has been referenced by it.

Comment: I was working with servlets so every time i make changes to java file and compile it i have to manually cut/paste the .class file in the "classes" folder. Thats why asked this question

Comment: If you're compiling by hand, you might want to check out the `-d` option of the `javac` command, which will tell the compiler where to put the compiled `.class` files.

Comment: Compiler put .class files in the same directory structure as the sources are in the package structure. You shouldn't cut/paste .class files. You should set servlet mappings in your web.xml file. Can you show your web.xml?